# Reduce Image height without loosing quality

Tags: image, photoshop

I have a text logo image in photoshop of size 2500 x 1316 px. The text is very clear and crisp in this size. I have to put it on a website and the height of logo should be around 40px - 50px. When i change image dimensions in photoshop to 45px, it becomes blurry when applied on the website.
Is there a way to reduce height to 45px and still maintain the quality of image? So that its easily readable?
I have tried Bicubic Sharper but same result.

Comment: Is it possible to share the original logo and the output logo?

Comment: You can download file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/logocopy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you scale it down to a low dimension and then in the web page, you make it larger and it gets bad blurry or has other problems.

My suggestion is: `simply use the original image in the web page without scaling and make sure aspect ratio is not changing in the web page`

Normally, the quality is good when you scale down but not scale up.

Check [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fnyudri.files.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F12%2Fah-logo-xl.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fnyudri.wordpress.com%2F&docid=7t4JA4J5JVVB8M&tbnid=laTldAbXRTgyPM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjno43yhuPSAhUl9IMKHfxrAKUQMwhqKAkwCQ..i&w=6000&h=6000&bih=770&biw=1600&q=nyu%20logo&ved=0ahUKEwjno43yhuPSAhUl9IMKHfxrAKUQMwhqKAkwCQ&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=6000&imgrc=laTldAbXRTgyPM:&vet=10ahUKEwjno43yhuPSAhUl9IMKHfxrAKUQMwhqKAkwCQ..i&w=6000) and [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2Fc6%2Fba%2F72%2Fc6ba72370d0732b72d263f96edd4c9ae.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F11962755240124140%2F&docid=rjZLq3iFoz8_JM&tbnid=goWwhYl5VzbtTM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjno43yhuPSAhUl9IMKHfxrAKUQMwhlKAQwBA..i&w=4500&h=4500&bih=770&biw=1600&q=nyu%20logo&ved=0ahUKEwjno43yhuPSAhUl9IMKHfxrAKUQMwhlKAQwBA&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=4500&imgrc=goWwhYl5VzbtTM:&vet=10ahUKEwjno43yhuPSAhUl9IMKHfxrAKUQMwhlKAQwBA..i&w=4500). Original size is `6000*6000` and `4500*4500` but the quality in google is perfectly fine without any blur.

Also, when saving the logo, make sure it is an uncompressed type such as `.bmp` not `.jpg`

Comment: I used the same image without scaling and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A properly created logo should never be manipulated as a raster graphic. If you want a crisp result at that kind of resolution reduction, you're much better off getting ahold of the original vector version of the logo.

ALSO, no graphic is going to be "crisp" when reduced from 2500 to 50px. That's just far too much reduction for detail retention.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a bigger image to use on photoshop, and if it is text, just make it bigger, but if there is an image, you should find a bigger image, if you can.

Comment: The image is fairly large and in good quality at 2500px. Problem is when the height is reduced, quality decreases.